# Running Node as a service with PM2 - connection refused

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean, pm2

I am following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial for setting up a node project on a Digital Ocean Ubuntu distribution. `systemctl status pm2` shows the service is online:

```
App name │ id │ mode │ pid   │ status  │ restart │ uptime │ memory      │ watching
server   │ 1  │ fork │ 19999 │ online  │ 0       │ 0s     │ 21.219 MB   │ disabled │
```

However I get a connection refused error when I attempt to navigate to the domain. The application starts fine on port 5000 if I run it with npm start. I have Nginx installed and configured as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name <mysite.com>;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

Node version is v6.3.0 and pm2 version is 1.1.3.

Comment: have you tried running it with just node and not with pm2

Comment: Do you mean with ```npm start```? If so, yes it works that way.

Comment: have you tried just with the domain name or have you tried the ip address of the server. Yoh could have your domain incorrectly configured.

Comment: I get a 502 Bad Gateway response.

Comment: Do you have a firewall on that ip? I would also reccomend you check your proxy server settings.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced something similar:

---

1. Running with `node` using `node dist/app.js`, the TCP server was accessible as expected:

```
$ nc -vz 1.1.1.1 5000
> Connection to 1.1.1.1 port 5000 [tcp/commplex-main] succeeded!
```

(Note: not the real IP address ^^^)

2. Running with `pm2` using `pm2 restart dist/app.js`, the TCP server refused connections:

```
$ nc -vz 1.1.1.1 5000
> nc: connectx to 1.1.1.1 port 5000 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

---

After checking my `.env`, I realised I had accidentally left my server host IP on the development localhost `127.0.0.1` instead of changing it to the public interface `0.0.0.0`.

After switching to the public interface `0.0.0.0`, they behaved the same way & connections were successful.

Perhaps instead of taking that route, it is best to configure Nginx as a reverse proxy server for TCP with `stream` using this different Digital Ocean tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-develop-a-node-js-tcp-server-application-using-pm2-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04#step-4-%E2%80%94-set-up-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-server