# configure nodejs api using pm2 apache

Tags: node.js, apache, puppet, pm2

I have nodejs app running on centos 7 using pm2

on server when I run

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:3021/products
```

It returns me data as expected.

Now I like my api to accessible outside server.

So I am trying to configure some kind of reverse proxy?

I am already have Apache running and configured using puppet module on server https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/apache

```
apache::vhost { 'my-api.local':
        port => 80,
        proxy_preserve_host => true,
        proxy_dest_match => 'http://127.0.0.1:3021',
        docroot           => '/opt/nodejs-apis/my-api.local/current/build',
      }
```

I have entry in my host file 
which is pointed my-api.local to my vagrant box ip.

when I access http://my-api.local in browser I get following

```
{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Invalid URL: //"}
```

Any idea what I am missing?

some useful links

[Running Node as a service with PM2 - connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277557/running-node-as-a-service-with-pm2-connection-refused)
https://www.tecmint.com/install-pm2-to-run-nodejs-apps-on-linux-server/

### Update

after watching this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTdv_DzwTS0

I even have changed my vhost file which now looks like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName my-api.local
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3021/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3021/
</VirtualHost>
```

But still no luck :(

Comment: make sure you start the app on `0.0.0.0` as well. `express` may does that on default but other frameworks may not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after spending hours :(, finally this one solved it

```
  apache::vhost { 'my-api.local':
    port => 80,
    proxy_preserve_host => true,
    proxy_pass          => { 'path' => '/', 'url' => 'http://localhost:3021' } ,
    docroot             => false,
  }
```

Which generated this in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ as above

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName my-api.local
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3021/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3021/
</VirtualHost>
```

But also need to refresh pm2 service..
Don't forget to call api :) such as http://my-api.local/products

Thanks to https://serverfault.com/questions/804795/puppet-apache-vhost-proxypassreverse-configuration for clue

Comment: Invalid command 'ProxyPreserveHost', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in